# How to find expression for 2 variables function

Tags: functions

I have some function $f(x,y)$ that I don't know. I know that
$$\begin{aligned}f(-1,0) &= -1\\ f(-0.75,0.75) &= 0.75\\
f(0,1) &= 1\\
f(0.75,0.75) &= 1\\
f(1,0) &= 1\end{aligned}$$

Whats the easiest way to find the expression that $f(x,y)$ equals?

Comment: Welll... it's not linear, so this might be a hard hunt.  Do you have a source for the known data points, or a place this function is used?

Comment: How about using Lagrange interpolation, in 2 variables?